# Потокобезопасность передачи параметра по ссылке

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Интересует, является ли потокобезопасной передача параметра по ссылке. Например, есть такой код:

```
void func(SomeClass & v)
{
    // ... что-то делаем с v
}
```

Возможна ли такая ситуация, что объект, переданный в функцию `func` по ссылке `(v)`, каким-либо образом выйдет из своей области видимости (в другом потоке) и будет уничтожен,
а в данной функции func ссылка на этот объект станет недействительной? Я такой ситуации себе представить не могу, но, может быть, такое возможно?

Думаю, вопрос можно перефразировать так: а возможно ли, вообще, передать ссылку на объект, созданную в одном потоке, в другой поток?

По мотивам программы от VladD'a накропал такую программку для эксперимента:

```
class A
{
public:
    int m_a;
    A() {
        m_a = 10;
    }
    void print(string s) {
        cerr << "A::print(): " << s.c_str() << "A::m_a == " << m_a << "\n";
    }
    ~A() {
        m_a = 50;
        cerr << "Объект A уничтожен\n";
    }
};

class Container
{
public:
    A& ref;
    Container(A& v) : ref(v) {}
    ~Container() {
        cerr << "Объект Container уничтожен\n";
    }
};

void ThreadProc(Container* c)
{
    cerr << "Мы в порожденном потоке, щас воспользуемся ссылкой";
    sleep(5);
    // пользуемся, и ... не вылетаем, однако!:
    c->ref.print("воспользовались: ");
    c->ref.m_a = 100;
    c->ref.print("еще раз воспользовались: ");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    {
        A a;
        Container c(a);
        thread t (ThreadProc, &c);
        t.detach();
        cerr << "Порожденный поток отделен.\n";
    }
    sleep(10);
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
Порожденный поток отделен.
Объект Container уничтожен
Объект A уничтожен
Мы в порожденном потоке, щас воспользуемся ссылкой
A::print(): воспользовались: A::m_a == 50
A::print(): еще раз воспользовались: A::m_a == 100
```

И никаких exception.
Т.е. получается, что объект по ссылке передать в другой поток возможно.
И даже, когда этот объект уничтожается (выходит из области видимости - выполняется его деструктор) в основном потоке, то другой поток все равно может им как-то пользоваться.
Как это возможно?
Вопросов становится все больше.

Comment: @VladD, придется писать сюда. Итак, по порядку:
1) естественно, что передача по ссылке НАМНОГО дешевле передачи по значению,
2) в многопоточных приложениях я не могу и не должен делать так, чтобы "каждый кусок кода нёс ответственность за ссылки, которые он выдаёт наружу", иначе это будет кошмар, а не программирование,
3) Вы написали, что "Если функция получает shared_ptr по ссылке, и хочет сохранить его, она обязана скопировать его внутри". Но мало ли что хочет функция, ведь мы не знаем, как шедулер распределяет потоки на выполнение.

Comment: @VladD: Может получиться, что мы не успеем скопировать, а внешний shared_ptr уже будет разрушен. Просто все это меня наталкивает на мысль, что функция, получив ссылку в качестве аргумента как бы владеет этим объектом и может полностью надеяться, что этот объект не разрушается, как минимум, пока не выполнится тело функции.

Comment: @komandor: Почему же? Проблем не вижу. Если вы передаёте ссылку в поток — размещаете её в контейнере, который лежит в heap'е, и передавайте его в поток через (например) `shared_ptr` (причём по значению).

Если вас вызывают из другой функции, вызывающая сторона должна позаботиться о том, что пока ваша функция не отработает, переданный объект будет жив. Если вы запускаете новый поток, вы должны обеспечить валидность параметров. Например, вы можете возложить ответственность за деаллокацию параметров на код в новом потоке.

Comment: @komandor: Вообще вопрос о владении тем или иным объектом — ключевой в C, и почти ключевой в C++. Вы должны в любой момент знать, какой код ответственен за какой объект, и проектировать систему так, чтобы не было доступа к уничтоженным объектам. (Это самая большая головная боль, которой нет в языках с garbage collector'ами.) Вы можете изобретать любые протоколы обмена информацией о нужности объектов. Например, один поток может извещать другой о том, что ему больше не нужны оригинальные параметры.

Ответственность за правильность лежит в любом случае на вас как архитекторе программы.

Comment: @komandor, можете также почитать немного о [libstdc++ и multithreaded applications](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_concurrency.html).

Если откровенно, я так до конца и не понимаю, что именно Вас в этом вопросе так беспокоит?

Неужели то обстоятельство, что компилятор не отслеживает все потенциально небезопасные действия программиста? Если так, то Вы слишком много ждете от его авторов.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Разобрался. В общем, если не использовать ссылки извращенным способом, типа упаковки в контейнер и последующей передачи его в другой поток, то ссылки вполне безопасны. Ответ на свой вопрос сформулирую так: передача объекта в другой поток по ссылке не является потокобезопасной, т.к. объект может быть уже разрушен в исходном потоке. То же самое можно применимо и к указателям. Вместо передачи по ссылке между потоками следуюет использовать передачу по значению (например, через shared_ptr). Передачу по ссылке следует использовать при вызове функций текущего потока!

Comment: @komandor, программирование потоков с разделяемой памятью вообще крайне небезопасная (непредсказуемая, чреватая множеством ошибок и разочарований в ее эффективности) область.

Не думаю, что столь простые выводы смогут облегчить Вашу участь, если Вы все же решились ступить не этот скользкий путь.

Comment: @komandor: Вы можете передавать объект в другой поток как по ссылке, так и по указателю, если вы можете обеспечить его валидность по крайней мере до тех пор, пока поток не закончит работу с ним.

Передача как по ссылке, так и по указателю неверна, если вы не можете обеспечить этого.

Если вы передаёте копию, вы очевидно обеспечиваете валидность, т. к. теперь владельцем объекта-копии является другой поток.

Не думайте в терминах ссылок, указателей и других _механизмов_, думайте в терминах владения и жизненного цикла объектов.

Answer (score 2):

Ещё как да. C++ — не memory safe, в нём легко выстрелить себе в ногу^W^W^W^W закодировать undefined behaviour.

Пример:

```
SomeClass& ProduceDeadReference()
{
    SomeClass sc;
    return sc;
}

...
SomeClass& v = ProduceDeadReference();
// тут ссылка уже мёртвая
std::thread t(ThreadProc, v);

void ThreadProc(SomeClass& v)
{
    // а тут тем более
}
```

---

Классическое дополнительное чтение по теме: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/276994) (очень рекомендую).

---

Уточнение по коду. Вот этот код [компилируется](http://ideone.com/U5FtqV):

```
#include <thread>

class SomeClass {};

SomeClass& ProduceDeadReference()
{
    SomeClass sc;
    SomeClass* p = &sc; // подавим warning заодно
    return *p;
}

class Container
{
    SomeClass& ref;
public:
    Container(SomeClass& v) : ref(v) {}
};

void ThreadProc(Container* c)
{
    // пользуемся, вылетаем
}

int main()
{
    Container c(ProduceDeadReference());
    std::thread t(ThreadProc, &c);
    return 0;
}
```

---

По поводу того, что ваш код *не вылетает*. Память, оставшаяся после мёртвого объекта, может в любой момент быть выделена другому объекту. Ссылка фактически ссылается именно на эту память. Таким образом, работать с объектом по невалидной ссылке — всё равно что стрелять с закрытыми глазами, «на кого бог пошлёт». Можете попасть в стенку, а можете и в человека.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что я так уже пробовал. Такой код даже компилятор не пропустит. Вот если функция ThreadProc будет принимать не ссылку, а значение, тогда компилируется. Так что вопрос в силе.

Comment: Спасибо, новая версия компилируется. Но:
1) компилятор все равно сообщит о вероятной ошибке - reference to local variable returned,
2) вылетаем мы, даже если не пользуемся битой ссылкой (с пустым телом ThreadProc) - бросается исключение из деструктора thread,
3) мы заранее передаем в поток дохлую ссылку (о чем предупреждает компилятор), а  интересует другая ситуация: мы передаем живую ссылку из одного потока в другой, затем в первом потоке объект, указываемый ссылкой, уничтожается, а второй поток хочет работать с уже дохлой ссылкой.
Щас пытаюсь еще раз поэкспериментировать на эту тему.

Comment: Написал экспериментальную программку: добавил к вопросу выше. Теперь вообще не понятно: программа не вылетает, хотя из другого потока идет обращение через ссылку к локальной переменной основного потока, причем, уже ПОСЛЕ разрушения этой переменной в основном потоке. Это как?

Comment: @komandor, а в чем проблема-то?

Ссылка это тот же указатель. От этого и отталкивайтесь в своих размышлениях.

Проверить просто. Создайте что-нибудь с ID (скажем, 1) через `new`. Передайте в создаваемый поток ссылку на этот объект и сделайте sleep(1). В новом потоке сделайте sleep(2). В первом потоке сделайте delete и тут же new нового объекта с ID = 2. Скорее всего он будет размещен в той же памяти, что и первый. Распечатайте ID переданного во второй поток объекта.

Думаю, должно получиться ID == 2. 

Если нет, то воспользуйтесь собственным  примитивным allocator-ом для new.

Comment: С другой стороны, а в чем тут отсутствие потокобезопасности?

Сама ссылка, переданная в новый поток не меняется. Измениться может содержимое памяти, на которую эта ссылка указывает. А это уже совсем другая история.

Вот передавать адрес (или ссылку) локальной переменной, которая может меняться в первом потоке -- это небезопасно. Например, если вы в цикле запускаете потоки и передаете номер итерации, то так

     for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        pthread_create(..., func, (void *)&i); // нельзя

а так

     ...
        pthread_create(..., func, (void *)i); // можно

Comment: @komandor: А вы почитайте текст по ссылке, лучше чем Эрик я всё равно не объясню.

А warning можно спрятать. Например:

    size_t ZeroOffset() { return 0; }
    SomeClass& ProduceDeadReference()
    {
        SomeClass sc;
        size_t x = &sc;
        return *(SomeClass*)x;
    }

Comment: История появления вопроса: в с++ передача параметра по ссылке используется всюду. Например, при конструировании shared_ptr или присвоении используются ссылки на shared_ptr-источники:

    template<typename _Tp1>
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<_Tp1>& __r) ...
По идее, было бы безопасно передать в этот к-р другой умный указатель не по ссылке, а по значению. Это гарантировало бы, что никто извне этого конструктора не удалит объект, на который указывает r. Однако так не сделано.
Неужели код, в котором есть передача данных по ссылке (т.е. вся библиотека c++) не потокобезопасен? Сомневаюсь.

Comment: @komandor: Смотрите.

Передача по ссылке (немного) дешевле, чем передача по значению, т. к. при передаче по значению происходит копирование. Это раз. Во-вторых, каждый кусок кода несёт ответственность за ссылки, которые он выдаёт наружу. Таким образом, если все делают всё правильно, то проблем не будет. И в третьих, если объект уничтожить, то передача указывающего на него `shared_ptr` как по значению, так и по ссылке одинаково приведёт к проблемам.

(У вас вышел лимит комментариев, удаляйте старые.)

Comment: @komandor: Если объект корректно размещён в heap'е, и его никто не удаляет вручную, то проблем не будет при любом типе передачи, т. к. объект будет удалён лишь с удалением **последнего** `shared_ptr`, указывающего на него. Если функция получает `shared_ptr` по ссылке, и хочет сохранить его, она обязана скопировать его внутри, т. к. разумеется переданный `shared_ptr` может умереть после окончания работы функции.

Comment: @komandor: Убивать `shared_ptr`, переданный функции, _во время её работы_ нельзя: вы «выдёргиваете из-под неё стул» таким образом. Функция имеет право расчитывать, что её параметры не будут уничтожены пока она не отработает. Если ей нужен этот указатель и после — надо завести свою собственную копию.

Потоки тут вовсе не при чём, копировать чужой объект надо в любом случае, что в случае доступа из другого потока, что в случае доступа позже из этого же потока.